# Count distinct value of column regardless change in other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| Whisper | Client  | Tenant | Ring |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| W1      | iOS     | T3     | R1   |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| W2      | iOS     | T2     | R1   |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| W1      | Android | T3     | R1   |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| W2      | Android | T2     | R1   |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
| W3      | Android | T4     | R2   |
+---------+---------+--------+------+
```

And I want to count distinct Whispers knowing that there is a change in client column, currently I'm using this:

```
WhipserCounts =
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Whipser) AS Whispers,
                Client,
                Tenant,
                Ring
FROM InputData
GROUP BY Client, Tenant, Ring;
```

But I see that W1 and W2 are counted twice for each client but I need to consider them as one no matter the client is, so for the first time If I got iOS I need to set the client by the first value. (Knowing that I need the client in the output table in the same time).

What I got:

```
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| Whispers | Client  | Tenant | Ring |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | iOS     | T3     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | iOS     | T2     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | Android | T3     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | Android | T2     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | Android | T4     | R2   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
```

What I need:

```
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| Whispers | Client  | Tenant | Ring |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | iOS     | T3     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | iOS     | T2     | R1   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
| 1        | Android | T4     | R2   |
+----------+---------+--------+------+
```

Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to use `MAX()`, not group by :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Whipser) AS Whispers,
                MAX(Client),
                Tenant,
                Ring
FROM InputData
GROUP BY Tenant, Ring;
```

Comment: This will discard any other clients but in the same time will discard it's count!

Comment: It's not logical, you want to group by Whisper  and Tenant but you want also show All the Client too, you just can't do them together, it's out of logic

Comment: I will edit the question, you are right.
Actually I want to count it as one :) 
Thank you this will work :)

Comment: Glad to help you !